# "KoinApplication has not been started" while running KMM app on iOS, works in android

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, kotlin-multiplatform, koin

I have been stuck on this issue for 2 days and I am on the verge of breaking my computer.

I am creating a Rick And Morty app using KMM, GraphQL and  SQLDelight and all the dependency injection is done through Koin. The thing is, everything works pretty fine in Android but (how come?) iOS is creating difficulties this time. Even though I am initializing Koin in @main, the app crashes instantly when I try to use my lazily injected use case.

Let me explain it better in the code:

- The app is built on layer-by-layer multi-modules.
- I have layers of core (where I put my models), data (database and networking), domain (mappers and use cases), di (where I have a DIHelper that starts Koin) and state (the place I share my ViewModel logic as black-box state-machines, so each view model has a state machine that does the logic on the presentation layer).
- In my CharacterListStateMachine, I have:

```kotlin
class CharacterListStateMachine(
    scope: CoroutineScope? = null
) : BaseStateMachine<CharacterListEvent>(
    coroutineScope = scope
) {

    private val getAllCharactersUseCase: GetAllCharacters by inject()

    private val _currentPage = MutableStateFlow(1)

    private val _currentState = MutableStateFlow(CharacterListState())
    val currentState = _currentState.asStateFlow().toCommonStateFlow()

    init {
        stateMachineScope.launch {
            _currentPage.collect { currentPage ->
                getAllCharactersUseCase(page = currentPage).collect { resource ->
                    _currentState.update {
                        it.copy(
                            isLoading = resource == Resource.Loading,
                            hasNoData = resource == Resource.EmptyOrNull,
                            error = if (resource is Resource.Error) resource.message else "",
                            data = if (resource is Resource.Success) resource.data else emptyList()
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onEvent(event: CharacterListEvent) {
        when(event) {
            CharacterListEvent.LoadMore -> {
                _currentPage.value += 1
            }
        }
    }

}
```

- And BaseStateMachine is:

```kotlin
    abstract class BaseStateMachine<T>(
        val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope? = null
    ) : KoinComponent {
        val stateMachineScope = coroutineScope ?: CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

        abstract fun onEvent(event: T)
    }
```

- On the Android side, I can create a Jetpack ViewModel, so that I can pass the viewModelScope to the state machine and everything works fine with different dispatchers, such as:

```kotlin
    class CharacterListViewModel: ViewModel(), KoinComponent {
        private val stateMachine : CharacterListStateMachine by inject {
            parametersOf(viewModelScope)
        }
        val state = stateMachine.currentState
        // TODO: Add event handling later
    }
```

- I have a similar approach on the iOS side, and as I can not pass any CoroutineContext to the state machine, the BaseStateMachine will initialize the scope with the default parameter, which is MainDispatcher:

```swift
    import Foundation
    import state
    import core

    @MainActor
    class CharacterListVM: ObservableObject {
        private let stateMachine: CharacterListStateMachine
        private var handle: DisposableHandle?
        
        @Published
        var currentState: CharacterListState = CharacterListState(
            isLoading: true,
            hasNoData: false,
            error: "",
            data: []
        )
        
        init() {
            self.stateMachine = CharacterListStateMachine(scope: nil)
        }
        
        func startObserving() {
            stateMachine.currentState.subscribe { state in
                if let state = state {
                    self.currentState = state
                }
            }
        }
        
        func dispose() {
            handle?.dispose()
        }
        
    }
```

- DisposableHandle and how I handle the flow collecting is negligible at that point as it works and has nothing to do with starting Koin on the iOS side.
- So, when I start the app on the iOS side, CharacterListStateMachine crashes as it can not find the injected use case (at least, this is what I believe and have done/end up with), even though I am starting the Koin in @main such as:

```swift
    import SwiftUI
    import di

    @main
    struct iOSApp: App {
        init() {
            DIHelper().doInitKoin()
        }
        var body: some Scene {
            WindowGroup {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
```

- Inside the DIHelper, I define my modules and start Koin as:

```kotlin
    object DIHelper {
        private fun allModules() = dataModules + domainModules + stateModules

        fun initKoin(
            appDeclaration: KoinAppDeclaration = {}
        ) = startKoin {
            appDeclaration()
            modules(allModules())
        }

        // For iOS
        fun initKoin() = initKoin {}
    }
```

Finally, in my use case, I am fetching the characters such as:

```kotlin
    class GetAllCharacters(
        private val service: RickAndMortyService
    ) {
        suspend operator fun invoke(page: Int) : Flow<Resource<List<CharacterModel>>> = flow {
            emit(Resource.Loading)
            try {
                val response = service.getCharacters(page = page)
                if (response.isEmpty()) {
                    emit(Resource.EmptyOrNull)
                } else {
                    val mapped = response.filterNotNull().map { it.toCharacterModel() }
                    emit(Resource.Success(data = mapped))
                }
            } catch (e: NetworkErrors) {
                emit(Resource.Error(message = e.message))
            }
        }
    }
```

And in order to give more information about my modules:

- data/di modules:

```kotlin
    val databaseModule: Module = module {
        // get() refers to Driver Factory
        single<RickAndMortDatabase> { LikedContentManager(get()) }
    }

    val networkModule: Module = module {

        factory<ApolloClient> {
            ApolloClient
                .Builder()
                .serverUrl(ApiConstants.BASE_URL)
                .build()
        }

        // get() refers to Apollo Client
        single<RickAndMortyService> {
            RickAndMortyRepository(get())
        }

    }

    expect fun platformModule(): Module
    Android -> 
    actual fun platformModule(): Module = module {
        // get() refers to Android Context
        single { RickAndMortyDatabaseDriverFactory(get()) }
    }
    iOS ->
    actual fun platformModule(): Module = module {
        single { RickAndMortyDatabaseDriverFactory() }
    }

    // This is the list of models that I add on DIHelper.kt
    val dataModules = listOf(
        platformModule(),
        databaseModule,
        networkModule
    )
```

- domain/di modules:

```kotlin
    val remoteUseCasesFetchModules: Module = module {
        single {
            GetAllCharacters(
                get<RickAndMortyService>()
            )
        }
        single {
            GetAllEpisodes(
                get<RickAndMortyService>()
            )
        }
        single {
            GetAllLocations(
                get<RickAndMortyService>()
            )
        }
        single {
            GetCharacterById(
                get<RickAndMortyService>()
            )
        }
        single {
            GetEpisodeById(
                get<RickAndMortyService>()
            )
        }
        single {
            GetLocationById(
                get<RickAndMortyService>()
            )
        }
    }

    val remoteUseCasesSearchModules: Module = module {
        single {
            SearchCharacter(
                get<RickAndMortyService>()
            )
        }
        single {
            SearchEpisode(
                get<RickAndMortyService>()
            )
        }
        single {
            SearchLocation(
                get<RickAndMortyService>()
            )
        }
    }

    val localUseCasesCharacterModules: Module = module {
        // All get()'s resembles to RickAndMortyDatabase
        single { (context: CoroutineContext) ->
            GetLikedCharacters(
                get<RickAndMortDatabase>(),
                coroutineContext = context
            )
        }
        single {
            GetLikedCharacter(
                get<RickAndMortDatabase>()
            )
        }
        single {
            LikeCharacter(
                get<RickAndMortDatabase>()
            )
        }
        single {
            DislikeCharacter(
                get<RickAndMortDatabase>()
            )
        }
    }

    val localUseCasesEpisodeModules: Module = module {
        // All get()'s resembles to RickAndMortyDatabase
        single {(context: CoroutineContext) ->
            GetLikedEpisodes(
                get<RickAndMortDatabase>(),
                coroutineContext = context
            )
        }
        single {
            GetLikedEpisode(
                get<RickAndMortDatabase>()
            )
        }
        single {
            LikeEpisode(
                get<RickAndMortDatabase>()
            )
        }
        single {
            DislikeEpisode(
                get<RickAndMortDatabase>()
            )
        }
    }

    val localUseCasesLocationModules: Module = module {
        // All get()'s resembles to RickAndMortyDatabase
        single {(context: CoroutineContext) ->
            GetLikedLocations(
                get<RickAndMortDatabase>(),
                coroutineContext = context
            )
        }
        single {
            GetLikedLocation(
                get<RickAndMortDatabase>()
            )
        }
        single {
            LikeLocation(
                get<RickAndMortDatabase>()
            )
        }
        single {
            DislikeLocation(
                get<RickAndMortDatabase>()
            )
        }
    }

    // This is the list of models that I add on DIHelper.kt
    val domainModules = listOf(
        localUseCasesCharacterModules,
        localUseCasesEpisodeModules,
        localUseCasesLocationModules,
        remoteUseCasesFetchModules,
        remoteUseCasesSearchModules
    )
```

- state/di modules

```kotlin
    val stateMachinesModule: Module = module {
        factory<CharacterListStateMachine> { (context: CoroutineScope) ->
            CharacterListStateMachine(context)
        }
    }

    // This is the list of models that I add on DIHelper.kt
    val stateModules = listOf(
        stateMachinesModule
    )
```

The crash is:

```
Uncaught Kotlin exception: kotlin.IllegalStateException: KoinApplication has not been started
    at 0   state                               0x103a84f27        kfun:kotlin.Throwable#<init>(kotlin.String?){} + 123 (/opt/buildAgent/work/acafc8c59a79cc1/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Throwable.kt:25:37)
    at 1   state                               0x103a7dc0f        kfun:kotlin.Exception#<init>(kotlin.String?){} + 119 (/opt/buildAgent/work/acafc8c59a79cc1/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Exceptions.kt:23:44)
    at 2   state                               0x103a7dedb        kfun:kotlin.RuntimeException#<init>(kotlin.String?){} + 119 (/opt/buildAgent/work/acafc8c59a79cc1/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Exceptions.kt:34:44)
    at 3   state                               0x103a7e573        kfun:kotlin.IllegalStateException#<init>(kotlin.String?){} + 119 (/opt/buildAgent/work/acafc8c59a79cc1/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Exceptions.kt:70:44)
    at 4   state                               0x103c3366b        kfun:org.koin.core.context.MutableGlobalContext#get(){}org.koin.core.Koin + 219 (/Users/runner/work/koin/koin/core/koin-core/src/nativeMain/kotlin/org/koin/core/context/GlobalContext.kt:96:32)
    at 5   state                               0x103c15f63        kfun:org.koin.core.component.KoinComponent#getKoin(){}org.koin.core.Koin + 211 (/Users/runner/work/koin/koin/core/koin-core/src/commonMain/kotlin/org/koin/core/component/KoinComponent.kt:33:62)
    at 6   state                               0x1039fed3f        kfun:dev.subfly.state.characterList.CharacterListStateMachine.<init>$lambda$0#internal + 563 
    at 7   state                               0x103a0014f        kfun:dev.subfly.state.characterList.CharacterListStateMachine.$<init>$lambda$0$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$1.invoke#internal + 79 
    at 8   state                               0x103a968af        kfun:kotlin.native.concurrent.SafePublicationLazyImpl#<get-value>(){}1:0 + 591 (/opt/buildAgent/work/acafc8c59a79cc1/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/native/concurrent/Lazy.kt:187:32)
    at 9   state                               0x1039fe66b        kfun:dev.subfly.state.characterList.CharacterListStateMachine.<get-getAllCharactersUseCase>#internal + 211 
    at 10  state                               0x1039ff58b        kfun:dev.subfly.state.characterList.CharacterListStateMachine.$<init>$lambda$3$lambda$2COROUTINE$0.invokeSuspend#internal + 383 
    at 11  state                               0x1039ff92f        kfun:dev.subfly.state.characterList.CharacterListStateMachine.<init>$lambda$3$lambda$2#internal + 283 
    at 12  state                               0x103a003bf        kfun:dev.subfly.state.characterList.CharacterListStateMachine.$<init>$lambda$3$lambda$2$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$3.emit#internal + 123 
    at 13  state                               0x103a0050b        kfun:dev.subfly.state.characterList.CharacterListStateMachine.$<init>$lambda$3$lambda$2$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$3.$<bridge-NNNBN>emit#suspend(kotlin.Int;kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<kotlin.Unit>){}kotlin.Any#internal + 155 
    at 14  state                               0x103cad50f        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlowImpl.$collectCOROUTINE$0.invokeSuspend#internal + 2459 (/opt/buildAgent/work/44ec6e850d5c63f0/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/flow/StateFlow.kt:396:31)
    at 15  state                               0x103cadb53        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlowImpl.collect#internal + 291 (/opt/buildAgent/work/44ec6e850d5c63f0/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/flow/StateFlow.kt:381:22)
    at 16  state                               0x1039ffca3        kfun:dev.subfly.state.characterList.CharacterListStateMachine.$<init>$lambda$3COROUTINE$1.invokeSuspend#internal + 571 
    at 17  state                               0x103a887cf        kfun:kotlin.coroutines.native.internal.BaseContinuationImpl#resumeWith(kotlin.Result<kotlin.Any?>){} + 599 (/opt/buildAgent/work/acafc8c59a79cc1/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/coroutines/ContinuationImpl.kt:30:39)
    at 18  state                               0x103cbf03b        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask#run(){} + 2579 (/opt/buildAgent/work/44ec6e850d5c63f0/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/internal/DispatchedTask.kt:106:71)
    at 19  state                               0x103ce761b        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.DarwinMainDispatcher.dispatch$lambda$0#internal + 131 (/opt/buildAgent/work/44ec6e850d5c63f0/kotlinx-coroutines-core/nativeDarwin/src/Dispatchers.kt:42:23)
    at 20  state                               0x103ce798b        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.DarwinMainDispatcher.$dispatch$lambda$0$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$1.invoke#internal + 71 (/opt/buildAgent/work/44ec6e850d5c63f0/kotlinx-coroutines-core/nativeDarwin/src/Dispatchers.kt:41:13)
    at 21  state                               0x103ce7a6f        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.DarwinMainDispatcher.$dispatch$lambda$0$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$1.$<bridge-UNN>invoke(){}#internal + 71 (/opt/buildAgent/work/44ec6e850d5c63f0/kotlinx-coroutines-core/nativeDarwin/src/Dispatchers.kt:41:13)
    at 22  state                               0x103ce8acb        _6f72672e6a6574627261696e732e6b6f746c696e783a6b6f746c696e782d636f726f7574696e65732d636f72652f6f70742f6275696c644167656e742f776f726b2f343465633665383530643563363366302f6b6f746c696e782d636f726f7574696e65732d636f72652f6e617469766544617277696e2f7372632f44697370617463686572732e6b74_knbridge13 + 255 (/opt/buildAgent/work/44ec6e850d5c63f0/kotlinx-coroutines-core/nativeDarwin/src/Dispatchers.kt:41:13)
    at 23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x180132ee3        _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 23 
    at 24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x180134707        _dispatch_client_callout + 15 
    at 25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x180143fd7        _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1219 
    at 26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x180143b03        _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 39 
    at 27  CoreFoundation                      0x18039a783        __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 11 
    at 28  CoreFoundation                      0x180394de3        __CFRunLoopRun + 1911 
    at 29  CoreFoundation                      0x180394253        CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 583 
    at 30  GraphicsServices                    0x188eb7c9b        GSEventRunModal + 159 
    at 31  UIKitCore                           0x106296fef        -[UIApplication _run] + 867 
    at 32  UIKitCore                           0x10629af3b        UIApplicationMain + 123 
    at 33  SwiftUI                             0x10a74b34b        OUTLINED_FUNCTION_54 + 499 
    at 34  SwiftUI                             0x10a74b1eb        OUTLINED_FUNCTION_54 + 147 
    at 35  SwiftUI                             0x109f43473        OUTLINED_FUNCTION_16 + 87 
    at 36  viewiOS                             0x100b6cf73        $s7viewiOS6iOSAppV5$mainyyFZ + 39 (/Users/alitaha/AndroidStudioProjects/ricKMMorty/viewiOS/viewiOS/App/iOSApp.swift:<unknown>)
    at 37  viewiOS                             0x100b6d01b        main + 11 
    at 38  dyld                                0x100d55513        0x0 + 4308948243 
    at 39  ???                                 0x100e35e4f        0x0 + 4309868111 
    at 40  ???                                 0x492e7fffffffffff 0x0 + 5273292951185784831 
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@ac6b620, MainDispatcher]
        at 0   state                               0x103a84f27        kfun:kotlin.Throwable#<init>(kotlin.String?){} + 123 (/opt/buildAgent/work/acafc8c59a79cc1/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Throwable.kt:25:37)
        at 1   state                               0x103a7dc0f        kfun:kotlin.Exception#<init>(kotlin.String?){} + 119 (/opt/buildAgent/work/acafc8c59a79cc1/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Exceptions.kt:23:44)
        at 2   state                               0x103a7dedb        kfun:kotlin.RuntimeException#<init>(kotlin.String?){} + 119 (/opt/buildAgent/work/acafc8c59a79cc1/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Exceptions.kt:34:44)
        at 3   state                               0x103ce45e7        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException#<init>(kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext){} + 179 (/opt/buildAgent/work/44ec6e850d5c63f0/kotlinx-coroutines-core/native/src/internal/CoroutineExceptionHandlerImpl.kt:31:5)
        at 4   state                               0x103cbaaf3        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.internal#handleUncaughtCoroutineException(kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext;kotlin.Throwable){} + 1111 (/opt/buildAgent/work/44ec6e850d5c63f0/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/internal/CoroutineExceptionHandlerImpl.common.kt:47:33)
        at 5   state                               0x103c5d25f        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines#handleCoroutineException(kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext;kotlin.Throwable){} + 743 (/opt/buildAgent/work/44ec6e850d5c63f0/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/CoroutineExceptionHandler.kt:32:5)
        at 6   state                               0x103c5125b        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.StandaloneCoroutine.handleJobException#internal + 163 (/opt/buildAgent/work/44ec6e850d5c63f0/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/Builders.common.kt:194:9)
        at 7   state                               0x103c670eb        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.finalizeFinishingState#internal + 1123 (/opt/buildAgent/work/44ec6e850d5c63f0/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/JobSupport.kt:230:59)
        at 8   state                               0x103c70473        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCompletingSlowPath#internal + 1955 (/opt/buildAgent/work/44ec6e850d5c63f0/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/JobSupport.kt:909:16)
        at 9   state                               0x103c6fc97        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCompleting#internal + 695 (/opt/buildAgent/work/44ec6e850d5c63f0/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/JobSupport.kt:866:16)
        at 10  state                               0x103c6f7f3        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport#makeCompletingOnce(kotlin.Any?){}kotlin.Any? + 355 (/opt/buildAgent/work/44ec6e850d5c63f0/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/JobSupport.kt:831:30)
        at 11  state                               0x103c5081f        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine#resumeWith(kotlin.Result<1:0>){} + 219 (/opt/buildAgent/work/44ec6e850d5c63f0/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/AbstractCoroutine.kt:100:21)
        at 12  state                               0x103a88a17        kfun:kotlin.coroutines.native.internal.BaseContinuationImpl#resumeWith(kotlin.Result<kotlin.Any?>){} + 1183 (/opt/buildAgent/work/acafc8c59a79cc1/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/coroutines/ContinuationImpl.kt:43:32)
        at 13  state                               0x103cbf03b        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask#run(){} + 2579 (/opt/buildAgent/work/44ec6e850d5c63f0/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/internal/DispatchedTask.kt:106:71)
        ... and 22 more common stack frames skipped

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am losing my mind for 2 days on that issue, so please, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you starting koin in iOS application?
https://insert-koin.io/docs/quickstart/kmm/#injecting-dependencies-in-ios

Comment: @Praveen Yes, I have already stated in explanation.

Comment: `DIHelper().doInitKoin()` looks odd. Shouldn't it be `DIHelper.shared.doInitKoin()`?

Comment: @EvgenyK already tried it, not works :(